# NetSuite, Assembly Build: how do I force a client script to detect the AB's creation?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

So I have a script that runs on create of Assembly Builds. It works perfectly when creating the AB manually but when the Assembly Build is created from a PO and then an IR I get an issue. It seems that because the transaction is generated automatically by NetSuite it does NOT trigger my User Event scripts afterSubmit function and then the development does not run.

Any ideas on how to force it to trigger the UE?

Comment: I'm guessing the deployment isn't restricted by role or employee etc, that would stop it triggering ? Have you tried creating a custom workflow action instead ?

Comment: You guessed correct. It is on all roles and executes as admin. Not only that but when the Assembly Build is created manually it dose get picked up by the User Event. The issue is when the Assembly Build is created automatically when a Item Receipt that was created from a Purchase Order gets saved.

I have no tried a workflow yet because in my experience the scripts are able to catch more events then workflows and not the other way around but I will try it anyway just to make  sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netsuite has a hard limitation that one UserEvent script cant trigger another UserEvent script. (maybe their worst idea ever, but it's a thing)
I'm guessing that the PO is generating the AB in its UserEvent script, and that is why the AB's userEvent script is not firing.
To get around this, you could write a scheduled script that processes any new AB's (maybe add a field that gets set when it is processed), then in the P.O. and any other relevant records afterSubmit events, you could tigger the scheduled script to handle any new assembly builds.
However you choose to solve it, you will likely have to do it in the afterSubmit events of the PO IR records.

Comment: *sigh* NetSuite limitations are the bane of my existence... I ended up doing something similar. I created a checkbox and a MR that runs every 15 min to submit the new AB's. I don't like it. It works. It is what it is.

Comment: "I don't like it, but it works" is the sadly what all Netsuite developers are forced to say on far too many occasions. Glad you found a serviceable solution.

Answer (score -1):

adding on to simons comment on the user event deployment under the context filtering you need to choose the execution context like user interface , user event script , csv import to let your script only execute on the following occasions

Comment: So as I stated on the comment the issue - as far as I can tell - is not with the Audience or the Context Filtering. I have all roles selected. The execution context also has all selected. Moreover as I stated it runs perfectly when the AB is created stand alone through the UI or a script. 
** The issue is when the NS System generates the AB when a IR is saved **